# Generating Linux X11 events?

Tags: linux, perl, mouseevent, x11

Alright, I'll start short and sweet and elaborate if necessary. Got a program that does some processing, not important what kind. In the end it has a series of events that need to be passed to the X11 server; mouse movements, buttons, and keypresses.

For now, we will assume that X11 is not properly monitoring the relevant `/dev/input/` files because... it isn't, and that's actually what this script aims to fix. Using Perl, I need to either:

1. Bypass the event files and communicate events to the server directly, (or)
2. Create and write to a new event file that X11 is guaranteed to obey, completely automatically, without prior configuration by the user, 100% of the time.

So the question I have for you, is which, and how?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like #2 is a red herring, so let's use Perl to talk to the X server.  https://metacpan.org/pod/X11::Protocol looks like it will let you do that.  It is a bit old, but the low-level X protocol is still compatible and it should get you close to what you're trying to do.

Comment: I looked into that briefly, but there is virtually *no* documentation or examples on how to use it. That page mentions a `SendEvent()` method and a related `pack_event()` method, but with no instructions or context for either. How do I send events to the core server instead of a window? What event hash does it want? Does it parse to a standard X11 event code? What event masks are at my disposal, and why would I bother? Google only tells me that so far, no one's ever been able to make it work (and say so online).

Answer (score 0):

[XTest](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/xextproto/xtest.pdf) extension allows you to simulate pointer/keyboard events. Unfortunately, X11::Protocol does not have this extension implemented so your options are

- implement it yourself (it's relatively easy, see [example](https://github.com/sidorares/node-x11/blob/master/lib/ext/xtest.js#L35) in my JS client)
- wrap external [program](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/) that talks to XTest
- talk to a server that talks to xtest ( some vnc client for perl ).

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the [X11::GUITest](https://metacpan.org/pod/X11::GUITest) module? It provides easy methods for automating X.

Comment: Using a test suite in a system's primary input seems kinda sketchy, but so far this is the only one with enough documentation to actually get running.

Comment: @DigitalMan Perl test modules have the namespace Test::. This module is named to match the Win32::GUITest module, the name for which came from a Dr. Dobbs article. If you research Win32::GUITest and X11::GUITest you'll find they are very often used for exactly this purpose.

Comment: I just posted the slides from my training course that cover (a bit) X11::GUITest http://edumaven.com/test-automation-using-perl/x-windows

Answer (score 0):

X11:GUITest is very useful and easy to use. Just notice there is one critical scenario to avoid.

1. GetWindowsFromPid() when you want to know all the windows of a specific process id, perhaps from StartApp().
2. For each window, you want to check or get attributes. So it's like to record GUIs by script instead of capturing by camera or image.
3. Notice some windows might be gone when you iterate the windows from step 1. Specifically, calling GetWindowPid will make perl exit abnormally, even wrapped by eval {};.
4. Actually, GetWindowPid is called inside GetWindowsFromPid, which sometimes exits abnormally, possibly due to the invalid window id to GetWindowPid.